# Update query with multiple innerjoins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update table with multiple inner joins however mysql is giving an error with no description

```
UPDATE videos v1
INNER JOIN parent_channel
ON (parent_channel.video_id=v1.video_id AND parent_channel.parent_type=“1”)
INNER JOIN parent_name
ON parent_name.item_id= parent_channel.parent_name_id
SET v1.video_name=parent_name.item_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not using real quotes in `parent_channel.parent_type=“1”`
change that to `parent_channel.parent_type="1"` or even `parent_channel.parent_type=1` if it's an integer.